# how to check if cells values are equivalent in excel but in different sheets

Tags: excel

how to check if cells values are equivalent in excel but in different sheets

Let's say if in sheet 1 in cell A1 value is John
and Let's if in sheet 2 in cell A1 value is Jermey

In third sheet I need to show if both values are equivalent or not.

If it's equivalent it should return true else false

How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the third sheet:

```
=IF('sheet1'!A1='sheet2'!A1;true;false)
```